# Technologies for making a web service that interacts with a REST API?

Tags: c#, json, rest, azure

My Google-foo is failing me here... most likely a terminology thing.

Basically, I'm making a desktop (and likely mobile) application that connects to a REST API that returns JSON. I've created a C# class library that handles the the data querying in my local project however this would expose my API key if I were to publish it.

I would like to know what are the appropriate options for simply running a small service in Azure that takes a web request, queries the API and passes the JSON response back. Something lightweight, decently scalable.

Is this something a web role or worker role is good for? Is this something I really should learn Node.js for?

Comment: Do take a look at Azure API App Service: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/api/ and see if it fits your requirement.

Comment: There's really no right answer to this. Web/worker role, mobile app, web app, VM... They all have their specific advantages. Your question then asks about language, and whether to learn node.js. Again, no right answer, since just about any language can be used to implement an API. Should you learn a different language for this? Not sure.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I haven't heard of that before. I can't determine if it is or isn't right yet, but I'll have a play with it.

Comment: Sorry, editing failed on me... as I thought there is a bunch of methods. Essentially running a full worker role (or web role) in azure could be overkill. It could be extremely ineffective. Where I have used them is in very different contexts.

Essentially its any client I make -> my service -> Someone else's RESTful API -> response to my service -> Data back to my client.

No data processing will happen. Its simply returning the raw json response back to the client. Node.js may be an ideal solution, but I've never used it and I'm struggling to find what is an effective choice.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question a few years back: [Keeping a secret key secret with Amazon Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240216/keeping-a-secret-key-secret-with-amazon-web-services)

One reasonable solution is to build a simple service that returns the headers and url to use when communicating with the authenticated service. Your API key remains secret because it only lives in your service, but the clients can leverage the API key by getting the encrypted request from your service and then making the request for the actual work.

I haven't personally looked into the [Azure API App Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/api/), but a brief browse of the main website suggests that it, too, may be relevant to your interests. :)

Comment: Cheers. I'll have to look into this, but I don't think a RESTful request is 'authenticated' first. I pretty sure it just pumps a single request; if the API key in the query-string is accepted, on their servers, it responds with the data.

Typically, you use a websites server side code to handle the REST request which obviously never passes the client's machines.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Azure Mobile Apps](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/mobile/).  Azure Mobile Apps is a "backend as a service" platform.  With Mobile Apps you can easily store information into a SQL Database and expose custom API methods.  It is a great place to start and has SDKs for connecting iOS, Andriod, Xamarin, and HTML apps.

As for security, the Mobile service has options to protect the data from allow anonymous access to requiring each user to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the whole framework is far overkill for what I need to do.

Comment: Then I would suggest writing a simple C# WebAPI or Node.JS API and publishing it to an Azure Web App. I don't think I fully understand your question.